# Subset columns of data frames contained in list based on matrix of indices

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I have a list that contains many data frames, and I have a matrix representing the index positions of columns of interest, with each row for each successive data frame. I am trying to subset each of the data frames within that list based on the matrix.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=letters[1:4], result1=1:4, result2=1:4, result3=1:4)
df2 <- data.frame(id=letters[1:4], result1=5:8, result2=1:4, result3=1:4)
df3 <- data.frame(id=letters[1:4], result1=9:12, result2=1:4, result3=1:4)
df4 <- data.frame(id=letters[1:4], result1=13:16, result2=1:4, result3=1:4)
dflist <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

indices <- matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,4,3),nrow=4, ncol=2)
```

So the data frames look like this:

```
[[1]]
  id result1 result2 result3
1  a       1       1       1
2  b       2       2       2
3  c       3       3       3
4  d       4       4       4

[[2]]
  id result1 result2 result3
1  a       5       1       1
2  b       6       2       2
3  c       7       3       3
4  d       8       4       4

[[3]]
  id result1 result2 result3
1  a       9       1       1
2  b      10       2       2
3  c      11       3       3
4  d      12       4       4

[[4]]
  id result1 result2 result3
1  a      13       1       1
2  b      14       2       2
3  c      15       3       3
4  d      16       4       4
```

and the index matrix looks like this

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    1    4
[4,]    1    3
```

From the first data frame, I want to subset columns 1 and 2, from the second dataframe I want columns 1, 2, from the third, I want columns 1 and 4, etc.

I can achieve this one by one using:

```
dflist[[1]][indices[1,]]
```

But I can't figure out a way to do for all at once (I tried `lapply()` and `sapply()` without luck)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop on the indices

```
lapply(1:4, function(i) dflist[[i]][indices[i,]])  # or 1:nrow(indices) as @bgoldst suggests
```

Or, using `mapply` to operate on the rows of `indices` and the `dflist`

```
mapply(function(a, b) a[,b], dflist, split(indices, row(indices)), SIMPLIFY = F)
```

This could be simplified further as suggested by @Frank, using `Map` (a wrapper for `mapply`) and removing the anonymous function

```
Map(`[`, dflist, split(indices,row(indices)))
```

Comment: ➕1 Should replace `1:4` with `nrow(indices)`.

Comment: I had done `1:length(dflist)` but your approach is more elegant. I think `seq_along(dflist)` works.

Comment: your `mapply` could instead be `Map(\`[\`, dflist, split(indices,row(indices)))`

Comment: @Frank yea that's nicer, although it does replace one extra function with another

Comment: @nongkrong I don't follow. `\`[\`` is just a shorter version of `function(a,b) a[,b]` when `a` is a data.frame... That was the only improvement I meant to suggest. I don't know which extra functions you're referring to.

Comment: @Frank it gets rid of the anonymous function, but adds `Map`, which then calls `mapply` with simplify=F.